# Facebook API. Can't publish on page with valid access token from PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm stuck trying to publish in a facebook page using the SDK in PHP 5.5. I want to make a php script to auto publish updates in a facebook page that I administer. When I make the request using the Graph API Explorer it works perfect, but I always receive the error message "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" when doing from the PHP script.

These are the steps and code I'm using:

1. Get a short-lived access token for my application using the "Get Access Token" option of the Graph API Explorer, with permissions manage_pages and publish_pages.
2. Get a never expire access token using the getOAuth2Client of the PHP SDK.
3. Get the page access token with the "/me/accounts" request
4. Send the publish request using the page access token and method "PORT /pageId/feed" with params: access_token and message

After getting the page access token, if I do the publish request using the Graph API Explorer it works, but from the PHP script it fails.

Here is the complete code I'm using:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';

$appId = 'my_app_id';
$appSecret = 'my_app_secret';
$pageId = 'my_page_id';

$shortToken = 'token got in step 1';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $appId,
  'app_secret' => $appSecret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
$longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($shortToken);

echo '<p>Long-live token: ' . $longLivedAccessToken . '</p>';

// Get page access_token
$request = $fb->request('GET', '/me/accounts');
$request->setParams(['access_token' => $longLivedAccessToken]);
try {
  $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
foreach ($graphEdge as $graphNode) {
  if ($graphNode['id'] == $pageId) {
    $pageAccessToken = $graphNode['access_token'];
  }
}
echo '<p>Page access token: ' . $pageAccessToken . '</p>';

$request = $fb->request('POST', '/' . $pageId . '/feed');
$request->setParams(['access_token' => $pageAccessToken, 'message' => 'Page publish test message']);

try {
  $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
?>
```

An output example:

```
Long-live token: XXXX
Page access token: XXX
Graph returned an error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

All the tokens are valid, checked using the Facebook Access Token Debugger. The page token info contains the app id, page id and my user id, with the manage_pages, publish_pages and public_profile permissions.

My application has default settings. I'm just added a platform of type "Website" with the URL of my webpage. The app is "live" and not submitted for approval (I've just create the application to auto publish messages in a Facebook page).

I've read a lot of messages and examples here and in Internet but I do not get it to work. I hope anyone can help me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: So what permission did you ask for?

Comment: Hello CBroe, I checked the manage_pages and publish_pages permissions when created the access_token. These are the permissions needed to post in a page right?

Comment: Yes. Have you made a debug output of your page access token, and checked it using the debug tool? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ Does it mention the page as “Profile ID”, and include the `publish_pages` permission?

Comment: Yes, sorry my wrong, so I can't check where is your authorization request, with publish_pages scope, I suggest you add authorization request code, let me erase my bad answer, i will post this comment in the main question. and sorry again.

Comment: CBroe, I check all the tokens generated with the debug tool and all are ok.
Juan, no entiendo muy bien a que te refieres con "authorization request". El token inicial lo genero desde la web de developers en el Graph API Explorer con la opción de "Get Token". Te refieres a eso? Ese token es el que luego pego en la variable $shortToken.
CBroe, Juan, as I mentioned in the question when I made the request with the same token, method, endpoint and parameters in the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) it works perfect.

Comment: Anyone could help please?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth. I was having the same issue. I realised I wasn't using the page's access token, I was using the `/me/` access token.

I have permissions for `publish_pages` and `manage_pages`.

For reference, I'm using the Lumen framework.

```
public function submitStock(Request $request){

  //first get Page token data from /me/accounts
  $pageTokenData = $this->fb->get("/me/accounts", $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])->getDecodedBody();

  $pageToken = null;

  //check get the token for the desired app
  foreach($pageTokenData['data'] as $account){
    if($account['name'] == "AppName"){
      $pageToken = $account['access_token'];
    }
  }

  //set message text from POST
  $message = $request->input('message');

  //send post using the Pages app token, not the /me/ token
  $this->fb->post('/'.$this->page.'/feed', 
    ['message' => $message], 
    $pageToken);


  return redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```